# Remove rows from a table which I collected from a loop (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that I loop with JQuery in order to find rows that match certain conditions:

```
 $('#sometable').find('tr').each(function () {  
   var row = $(this); //<----
    if(row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {   
//etc
   }   
}
```

My question is, is there a way to remove *each* matched row? I mean is there a way to collect these row variables inside my `if(row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))` so that I can remove the *specific* rows from my table directly?
Note that my rows don't have a unique `id`

Comment: you should use jquery filter method to achieve this..

Comment: @Mr_Green:Could you please give an example?I am new to JQuery

Comment: `$('#sometable').find('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').remove()`. removes all the checkboxes which are checked. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: @Mr_Green:No.I already go through a bunch of rows that match my condition. What I want is a way to remove these *specific* rows from the table if I have kept a reference to them from an array

Answer (score 0):

You may want:

```
$('#proposedtable tr:contains(input:checkbox:checked)').remove();
```

or

```
$('#proposedtable input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filteredRows = $('#sometable').find('tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'));
});
$(filteredRows).remove();
```

The above function will gather all the rows(tr) and then filter those rows based on the checked state of checkbox. Later the filtered rows will be removed.

---

*To make it as array, use [Array.prototype.slice.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)*

```
var arrFilteredRows = Array.prototype.slice.call(filteredRows);
```

Comment: I already have looped through the rows.If I store them in an array can't I remove them directly somehow?Is there an api to pass a row to an array to remove it?

Comment: @Jim Even if you have an array, you need to loop it to check the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Is this help you ?

http://jsfiddle.net/LGdA3/

```
<pre><code>
    $('input#myButton').on('click', function(){
        $('table#someTable td input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
           $(this).parents('tr').first().remove(); 
        });
    });
</code></pre>
```